# Insertar un entero en c#

Tags: c#

Llevo días intentando hacer un programa, que haga lo siguiente:

Pide un número entero al usuario.
A continuación, el programa pide tantos enteros como el número introducido previamente y los almacena en un vector.

A continuación el programa pide dos números enteros más: el primero corresponde a una posición y el segundo a un nuevo valor para insertar en el vector.
Finalmente el programa debe insertar el nuevo elemento en el vector en la posición introducida. Si la posición introducida es negativa, el nuevo elemento se insertará en la primera posición del vector. Si el número introducido es mayor que las posibles posiciones de la lista, el nuevo elemento se insertará en la última posición del vector.

Para resolver este ejercicio es necesario que crees una nueva función pública y estática de nombre insert () que reciba como parámetros un vector de enteros de nombre v, un número entero de nombre p y otro número entero de nombre e. La función debe devolver el vector de enteros resultante de añadir el elemento y en la posición p del vector v.

Unos ejemplos de uso de esta función podrían ser:

```
Insert total elements: 3 
Insert integer value: 1 
Insert integer value: 2 
Insert integer value: 3 
Insert position to insert element: 1 
Insert integer value to insert: 10 
The final values for the array are:  
1 
10
2
3
Press any key.
```

Otro ejemplo podría ser:

```
Insert total elements: 3
Insert integer value: 1
Insert integer value: 2
Insert integer value: 3
Insert position to insert element: 10
Insert integer value to insert: 10
The final values for the array are: 
1
2
3
10
Press any key.
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
Expected:
    Insert total elements: Insert integer value: Insert integer value: Insert integer 
    value: Insert position to insert element: 
    Insert integer value to insert: 
    The final values for the array are: 
    1
    10
    2
    3
    Press any key.
Got:
    Insert total elements: Insert integer value: Insert integer value: Insert integer 
    value: Insert position to insert element: Insert integer value to insert: 
    The final values for the array are: 
    10
    1
    2
    3
    Press any key.
```

Adjunto código:

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int i = 0;
            int pos = -1;
            int item = 0;
            int integer = 0;
            int limite;
            int[] arr = new int[10];

            Console.Write("Insert total elements: ");
            limite = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (i < limite)
            {
                Console.Write("Insert integer value: ");
                arr[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                i++;
            }


            Console.Write("Insert position to insert element: ");
            pos = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Insert integer value to insert: ");
            item = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (i = 5; i >= pos; i--)
            {
                arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
            }

            arr[pos - 1] = item;

            Console.WriteLine("The final values for the array are: ");
            while (integer < limite + 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arr[integer]);
                integer++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key.");
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Hola, anteriormente publicaste esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/580497/posiciones-de-enteros-en-c , te sugerimos evitar repetir preguntas, es importante realizar preguntas con base en [ask] para obtener la ayuda requerida,, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

como dije en l'anterior pregunta, te publico el código arreglado. El error era pequeño, también he puesto saltos de línea para que no sé quede todo en la misma línea y para ver resultado pon un Readline() vacío al final, sino la consola se cierra instantáneamente.

El error que hablo es que al asignar l'array el valor insertado le restabas -1 lo cual es lo normal, ya que aunque en programación las posiciones empiezan por el 0, en cambio, la gente normal cuando habla de la posición 1 se refiere a la primera posición. En el ejemplo, como tenías claro que la posición 0 es la primera, por lo que en tu codigo anterior 1=0,2=1,3=2...

Código con error arreglado:

```
arr[pos ] = item;//pos-1->1-1=0 el error está aquí
```

Otro error que no debes haber notado, ya que si escribes 0 siguiendo el ejemplo te saltaría error, porque l'array no puede recetar 0-1 puesto que -1 no es una posición de l'array posible.

Código del error Arreglado:

```
 for (i = arr.Length-1; i > pos; i--) //varía el número de vueltas por la longitud de l'array si llega al valor anterior a la posición buscada hace la última vuelta
        {
            arr[i] = arr[i-1 ];
        }
```

**Actualizado**

Cambio para que l'array sea variable:

```
 int[] arr;//solo lo declaro no lo inicializo

    Console.Write("Insert total elements: ");
    limite = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("\n");
    arr = new int[limite + 1];//array variable inicializándolo
```

Adaptación para que puedas inserir posiciones más grandes que l'array:

```
if (pos >= limite + 1)
            {
                int[] exarray = arr;
                arr = new int[pos + 1];//la posicion +1 para assegurar que entre
                for (int j = 0; j < exarray.Length; j++)
                {
                   
                    arr[j] = exarray[j];
                    
                }
            }
```

Codigo Completo:

```
        int i = 0;
        int pos = -1;
        int item = 0;
        int integer = 0;
        int limite;
        int[] arr;

        Console.Write("Insert total elements: ");
        limite = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("\n");
        arr = new int[limite + 1];//array variable
        while (i < limite)
        {
            Console.Write("Insert integer value: ");
            arr[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("\n");
            i++;
        }


        Console.Write("Insert position to insert element: ");
        pos = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   
        Console.Write("\n");//salto de linea
        if (pos >= 0) {
            if (pos >= limite + 1)
            {
                pos = limite;
            }
            Console.Write("Insert integer value to insert: ");
            item = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (i = arr.Length - 1; i > pos; i--) ///varía el número de vueltas por la longitud de l'array si llega al valor anterior a la posición buscada hace la última vuelta
            {
                arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
            }

            arr[pos] = item;//pos-1->1-1=0 el error esta aqui

            Console.WriteLine("The final values for the array are: ");
            while (integer < arr.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arr[integer]);
                integer++;
            }

       
        
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Position");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key.");
        Console.ReadLine();//Aguanta para ver el resultado
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por intentarme ayudar. Ahora tengo otro problema, y es que cuando indico una posicion más alta al número de enteros pedidos, el programa crashea.

Comment: Eso lo que tines que controlar con un if  el problema de las array es que no son variables, siempre tienen la longitud que las fijas al crearlas. Por cierto si usas el limite +1  al crear la int[] no tendrás el límite de 10 valores para el usuario

Comment: Te actualizo como lo puedes hacer

Comment: Actualizado he hecho que la longitud varía por el número total de elementos insertados +1 lo cual hace que puedas insertar mas de 10 elementos

Comment: He metido un if que evita que los usuarios exploten el programa con posiciones negativas y si es una posicion positiva y mayor que la longitud al ser las array fijas guardo los datos de l'array en una variable temporal creo una array con la longitud necessaria y añado los datos a la nueva array

Comment: @CapultaNT lo que he añadido se puede hacer más pequeño y "más optimizado", pero para que veas como se hace paso a paso y lo entiendas te he puesto la forma paso a paso

Comment: Tengo otro problema, y es que necesito que los ceros no tienen que salir

Comment: no quieres que salgan los 0 que indican que esta en la posicion 10, quieres que si es mas grande que el limite vaya a la ultima posicion ?

Comment: no, no los quiero.

Comment: directamente quiero que no existan esos espacios, o sea, que en vez de que la salida sea 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10 sea 1, 2, 3, 10

Comment: de acuerdo te lo monto es mas facil

Comment: hecho he actualizado el código completo simplemente si la posicion es mas grande que la que dan el límite lo inserto en la ultima posicon de l'array

Comment: ahora cuando envio el codigo me sale lo siguiente:
Expected:
    Insert total elements: Insert integer value: Insert integer value: Insert integer value: Insert position to insert element: 
    Insert integer value to insert: 
    The final values for the array are: 
    10
    1
    2
    3
    Press any key.
Got:
    Insert total elements: Insert integer value: Insert integer value: Insert integer value: Insert position to insert element: 
    The final values for the array are: 
    1
    2
    3
    0
    Press any key.

Comment: Entiendo que has metido de valores en cada line en de la siguiente forma 3, 1, 2, 3,0,10? en mi caso sale como el expected con el mismo codigo que hay en actualizado a la respuesta

Comment: Sí, lo he hecho así, y me sale el error.

Comment: esto es lo que escribe el expected: printf '3\n1\n2\n3\n%d\n10\n' -1

Comment: Actualiza tu código de la pregunta, esto no tiene sentido con el código más actualizado que te pasado